# Android ListView setOnItemClickListener doesn't work

Tags: android, listview

this simple code which has one listView into that, work fine, after move copy/paste that in other project, `setOnItemClickListener` doesn't work, all classes and `listview` id, activity layout are unique,why this listener doesn't work in project?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    private ListView               simple_list;
    private ArrayList<SimpleModel> data;
    private MyAdapter              adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        data = new ArrayList<>();
        simple_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.simple_list);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            data.add(new SimpleModel("Test " + i, "title " + i, "", ""));
        }

        adapter = new MyAdapter(this, data);
        simple_list.setAdapter(adapter);
        simple_list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ddddd " + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SimpleModel> {
        public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SimpleModel> users) {
            super(context, 0, users);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            SimpleModel data = getItem(position);
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ewallet_items, parent, false);
            }
            TextView e_account_number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.e_account_number);
            e_account_number.setText(data.getAccount_number());
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    public class SimpleModel {
        private String account_number;
        private String title;
        private String symbol;
        private String amount;

        public SimpleModel(String account_number, String title, String symbol, String amount) {
            this.account_number = account_number;
            this.title = title;
            this.symbol = symbol;
            this.amount = amount;
        }
    }
}
```

activity xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/simple_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@null"
        android:divider="@null"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

---

**PROBLEM RESOLVED**

parent listview items was clickable="true", after remove that line, my problem resolved

Comment: Can you share your ewallet_items.xml? It would be easy to figure if that has anything to do with this...

Comment: @TheCuriousDev Oh thank you very much sir, parent layout was clickable

Comment: My pleasure, The answer might help others who wants to have element which is clickable. Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your **ListView's row layout/item layout has some clickable elements** then **parent (row layout)** will **lose focus** and OnItemClickListener wont work anymore.

If your row layout/item layout has any clickable item then you must add this to your parent layout :

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

So the parent will get back its focus.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, Your post accepted and upvoted by me

Comment: My pleasure. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to create a new adapter for displaying your items you can cast your ArrayList to string easily by calling (String[])data.toArray()